# How to change TrailRenderer's space To LocalSpace

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

**How to make Local Space TrailRenderer**

I want to make TrailRenderer use Local Space. Because I use TrailRenderer in my Player's Sword Effect like that Image.

[image]

When the Player stopped in place, there is no problem. But as the player moves, the TrailRender moves too. So the TrailRenderer'shape is strange like that Image.

[image]

I tried all of TrailRenderer's Z Position set 0 But that's failed.

How to solve this Problem??

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class Trail : MonoBehaviour
{
    [SerializeField]
    private Transform _trailPos;
    TrailRenderer _renderer;

    [SerializeField] 
    private Vector3[] _t;

    private void Start()
    {
        _renderer = GetComponent<TrailRenderer>();
    }

    private void LateUpdate()
    {
        transform.position = _trailPos.position;
        for (int i = 0; i < _renderer.positionCount; ++i)
        {
            Vector3[] v = new Vector3[_renderer.positionCount];
            _renderer.GetPositions(v);
            for (int j = 0; j < v.Length; ++j)
            {
                v[j] = (Vector2)v[j];
            }
            _renderer.SetPositions(v);

        }
        _t = new Vector3[_renderer.positionCount];
        _renderer.GetPositions(_t);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could probably try and track your player movement and apply the same delta to the trail positions.

Something like e.g.

```
[SerializeField] private TrailRenderer trailRenderer;
[SerializeField] private Transform player;

private Vector3 lastFramePosition;

private void Start()
{
    lastFramePosition = player.position;
}

private void LateUpdate()
{
    var delta = player.position - lastFramePosition;
    lastFramePosition = player.position;

    var positions = new Vector3[trailRenderer.positionCount];
    trailRenderer.GetPositions(positions);

    for (var i = 0; i < trailRenderer.positionCount; i++)
    {
        positions[i] += delta;
    }

    trailRenderer.SetPositions(positions);
}
```